# Pass procedure output parameter to trigger body

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to pass the output of a procedure to a trigger body. Below is my attempt at what I think might be a very simple answer. Thanks!

```
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

DECLARE @id INT, @num_ids INT; 
EXEC [dbo].[i14_get_ids] 2, 1, @id OUTPUT, @num_ids OUTPUT; 
INSERT dbo.tbl_Events(
Event_ID, Location_ID, Event_Group_ID, 
Protocol_Name, Start_Date, 
ObjectID
)
SELECT 
a.Event_ID, a.Location_ID, a.Event_Group_ID, 
a.Protocol_Name, a.Start_Date, 
b.ObjectID
From
(SELECT 
Event_ID, Location_ID, Event_Group_ID, 
Protocol_Name, Start_Date
--deosn't work    
--ObjectID as @id

    --**********************************
FROM inserted) AS a 
--doesn't work
    @id ;

end
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to do, and how the above doesn't do that? Are you trying to insert the output from the stored procedure into the tbl_Events table? Are you aware that a trigger will fire once even if multiple rows have been inserted from the same statement?

Comment: This is somewhat related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241475/how-to-pass-procedure-output-to-multi-row-insert-statement but differ in that the application logic is limited to a single-row insert in this case, and I'm trying to use @id in the trigger code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is just a little off. You have a value in a variable, you don't have to make up some table or alias in order to access it.

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.Name_Of_Trigger_You_Left_Out
ON dbo.Name_Of_Table_You_Left_Out
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON; 

   DECLARE @id INT, @num_ids INT; 

   EXEC [dbo].[i14_get_ids] 2, 1, @id OUTPUT, @num_ids OUTPUT; 

   INSERT dbo.tbl_Events
   (
      Event_ID, Location_ID, Event_Group_ID, 
      Protocol_Name, Start_Date, ObjectID
   )
   SELECT 
      Event_ID, Location_ID, Event_Group_ID, 
      Protocol_Name, Start_Date, ObjectID = @id
   FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

The `ObjectID =` alias isn't necessary, I just wanted to make it obvious and explicit that it is a variable there. You had `ObjectID as @id` - this is backwards, you're saying "present the column ObjectID with the alias @id" - what you really meant was `@id AS ObjectID` - but again, in this case, it's just a value included in the select list, there is no strict need to provide an alias here.

If you're going to rely on this handling only single row inserts, you should probably consider enforcing that within the trigger by checking the number of rows in `inserted` before proceeding. Just because the application logic is limited does not mean this trigger won't fire for inserts that happen outside the control of your application logic, or that there will never be bugs in your application logic.

**EDIT**

To bypass the logic altogether if the requesting application is identified by its connection string as "My Cool Application":

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.Name_Of_Trigger_You_Left_Out
ON dbo.Name_Of_Table_You_Left_Out
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON; 

  IF NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
    WHERE session_id = @@SPID
    AND program_name = 'My Cool Application'
  )
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @id INT, @num_ids INT; 

    EXEC [dbo].[i14_get_ids] 2, 1, @id OUTPUT, @num_ids OUTPUT; 

    INSERT dbo.tbl_Events
    (
       Event_ID, Location_ID, Event_Group_ID, 
       Protocol_Name, Start_Date, ObjectID
    )
    SELECT 
       Event_ID, Location_ID, Event_Group_ID, 
       Protocol_Name, Start_Date, ObjectID = @id
    FROM inserted;
  END
END
GO
```

Or if it's identified by a login you could just check `IF SUSER_SNAME() <> 'MyMultiRowLogin'` or something similar...

Comment: interesting but true. There is only one application that "could" perform a multirow insert, and it uses a global login. Any chance I could disable this trigger if it's just this application peforming the insert?